# Restricting others to build the particular job in JENKINS

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins and I have a Project named **RetailcloudSolution_automation_cms2_prod** but I just want to restrict this job by others doesnt do the build  , but others can see , just shouldnt hit the Build  for security issue and I want only three people to Build this job for now and also for the future use, Is there anyway I can do this for just this particular JOB...? Can i know the steps to do it..? It should not affect globally, I need restriction just for project based..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to use the Role Strategy Plugin in jenkins to manage the Users.
With this plugin you manage users based on projects
In other words you can make sure that project or job is not runnable by other users.

Refer this link for better understanding and plugin configuration.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: But the thing is every user is an admin and I want to restrict other admins to build the job, except for few admins.. can we do that...?